# Solr Cloud (Solr 8.7.0) failed to talking to External Zookeeper Ensemble (Zookeeper v3.6.2)

Tags: docker, solr, docker-compose, apache-zookeeper, solrcloud

I have a zookeeper ensemble of size 3 with Zookeeper v3.6.2. Zookeeper ensemble is working fine. Then I launch solr cloud (Solr v8.7.0) with 2 nodes pointing zookeeper cluster. Solr cloud is working fine but if I go to the ZK Status on the Solr Admin portal it shows that it fails to talk to one of the zookeeper. Solr node-1 shows it can't connect to my zoo node-1 whereas solr node-2 shows it fails to connect to zoo node-3. I'm confused about what was wrong. It changes sometimes.
Here are the screenshots of ZK Status from the 2 different Solr Node-
[image] [image]
Is there anything I missed with zookeeper configuration?
Here is my Zoo config while running in docker-

```
  ZOO_MY_ID: 1
  ZOO_SERVERS: server.1=0.0.0.0:2888:3888;2181 server.2=${ZOO_NODE_02}:2888:3888;2181 server.3=${ZOO_NODE_03}:2888:3888;2181
  ZOO_TICK_TIME: 2000
  ZOO_INIT_LIMIT: 5
  ZOO_SYNC_LIMIT: 2
  ZOO_STANDALONE_ENABLED: 'false'
  ZOO_ADMINSERVER_ENABLED: 'true'
  ZOO_AUTOPURGE_PURGEINTERVAL: 0
  ZOO_AUTOPURGE_SNAPRETAINCOUNT: 3
  ZOO_MAX_CLIENT_CNXNS: 200 # default 60
  ZOO_4LW_COMMANDS_WHITELIST: mntr,conf,ruok
```

Whether I make the value of ZOO_STANDALONE_ENABLED true or false, the results are the same. Am I missing something with the latest version of zookeeper or solr?

Comment: Your configuration has `0.0.0.0` listed as one of the hosts. That will not point to the given host for other hosts in your cluster (which is what the error message tries to say - it can't connect to a ZK host on `0.0.0.0` and the listed nodes in ZK differs from those listed in your Solr configuration string. Use `10.10.31.226.2181` directly instead (which I assume match to `ZOO_NODE_01`).

Comment: Thanks @MatsLindh for your reply. But if I set the IP instead of 0.0.0.0 the zookeeper failed to bind the address for quorum connections. the error says - 

2021-02-10 11:12:01,888 [myid:3] - ERROR [ListenerHandler-/10.10.31.214:3888:QuorumCnxManager$Listener$ListenerHandler@1093] - Exception while listening
java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address (Bind failed)